# Invalid syntax when using "%" sign on print function on python 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, invalidation

I'm trying to print stuff on python 3.4.3 on the following way:

```
a=1    
b=2
print("text text %2d text text %2d", %(a,b))
```

but when I try to run this simple code it appears a mark exactly over the last "%" sign "invalid syntax":

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("text text %2d text text %2d", %(a,b))
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need comma after Your string :

```
print("text text %2d text text %2d" %(a,b))
```

> The % operator can also be used for string formatting. It interprets the left argument much like a sprintf()-style format string to be applied to the right argument, and returns the string resulting from this formatting operation

Also [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) says :

> because this old style of formatting will eventually be removed from the language, [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) should generally be used.

So you can use `str.format`:

```
print("text text {:2d} text text {:2d}".format(a,b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the comma:

```
print("text text %2d text text %2d", %(a,b))
#                                  ^
```

The `%` is an *binary operator*, it works on two inputs. Here those inputs are the string and the `(a, b)` tuple:

```
print("text text %2d text text %2d" % (a,b))
```